# Clone app from pagodabox using GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, powershell, github-for-windows, pagoda-box

I downloaded the [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), after installing it I try to clone my app i just created from Pagodabox. I'm using the PowerShell and try to clone it:

```
git clone git@git.pagodabox.io:apps/******.git *****
```

But there is an error: The SSH Key provided not authorized for this repo.
I dunno what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Add the public SSH Key of GitHub for Windows to Pagodabox**

The public key file is located in `C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\github_rsa.pub`. Open thefile and copy the key.
Open Pagodabox->SSH Keys-> New SSH Key. Give it a name then paste the key.

**2. Add the public SSH Key of Your App to GitHub**

Select your app-> Dev Config-> Public SSH Key. Copy the key.
Open GitHub-> Settings-> SSH Keys-> Add SSH Key. Give it a name then paste the key.

**3. Clone it**

Select your app-> Admin. Copy the git clone url.
Open the Git Shell installed together with GitHub application.
Run this command:
`git clone <the_git_clone_url> <the_name_you_desired>`

Thanks to @VonC for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [pagodabox git ssh troubleshooting page](https://pagodabox.io/docs/git_ssh_troubleshooting), and double-check that you have added your SSH Key to your user account.

The [basics of using git with Pagoda Box page](https://pagodabox.io/docs/git_basics) do mention as repo url only the ssh one, so it is important your ssh key is properly registered, but also accessible from your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh(\id_rsa[.pub])`.